# Change HTML form action based on selected option when submit button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

### HTML

```
<select class="form-control input-lg" id="r" name="r">
    <option data-action="/test1">Test1</option>
    <option data-action="/test2">Test2</option>
    <option data-action="/test3">Test3</option>
    <option data-action="/test4">Test4</option>
</select>
```

### jQuery

```
$("form").submit(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $("form").attr("action", $(this).children(':selected').attr("data-action")); 
  $(this).submit();
});
```

### Problem

Form action does not update and form does not submit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume that you have a form and a submit button *(since it is missing in your codes)*, what your planning can also be done this way:

Since you're using the attribute `data-`, you can get its value by using `data(nameOfData)`

**Using submit button**

```js
$("form").submit(function(e){
  var newMethod = $(this).find(':selected').data('action');
  $(this).attr('action', newMethod);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST">
  <select class="form-control input-lg" id="r" name="r">
    <option data-action="/test1">Test1</option>
    <option data-action="/test2">Test2</option>
    <option data-action="/test3">Test3</option>
    <option data-action="/test4">Test4</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Using a simple button**

```js
$("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
  var newMethod = $("#selectElement :selected").data('action');
  $(this).closest('form').attr('action', newMethod);
  $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST">
  <select id="selectElement" class="form-control input-lg" id="r" name="r">
    <option data-action="/test1">Test1</option>
    <option data-action="/test2">Test2</option>
    <option data-action="/test3">Test3</option>
    <option data-action="/test4">Test4</option>
  </select>
  <button type="button" id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

create a separate button like this:

HTML:

```
<!-- form html -->

<button type="button" id ="submit-btn" class="my-class">Submit!</button>
```

JS/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#submit-btn').on('click', function()
    {
        var action = $('form select option:selected').data('action');

        $.ajax({
            url: action,
            //rest of ajax code
        })
    })
});
```

instead of running the event on form submit, we execute the action via the button, which gets the action based on the selected option data-action value.

Comment: I don't want to submit via AJAX. I want form to submit and page to change as usual.

Comment: @user6888062 you don't have to use ajax - but it's 100% preferred, allows for better success/error messages as well as being more flexible to work with

Comment: to downvoter - happy but let me know what I can do to make it better, or else no one learns :)

Answer (score -1):

Use a button instead of submit button and submit the form inside the click event handler of the button. Inside the click handler, before submitting the form, change the action of the form.

I hope you can change the input type="submit" to type="button".